# $scope.apply() running twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs

I have used `$scope.apply()` inside a "`setTimeout`" function, but it seems that

my `$scope.apply()` is running twice.

```
setTimeout(function () {


    $scope.$apply(function () {


        $scope.proofName = cookie.getCookieId('assetName');



    });


}, 3000)
```

Please help me out to avoid running $scope.$apply() twice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/d9yax4gd/
You can simply remove $scope.$apply() because it internally fire in $digest cycle and $time uses it internally so use in angular way other wise it will throw error that $digest is in progress or you will find it get called multiple times

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout){
$scope.proofName = '';
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.proofName = cookie.getCookieId('assetName');    
}, 3000);
});
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setTimeout` you can use `$timeout`. In that case you don't need to do a `$apply` since the digest cycle will be run after the specified delay.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.proofName = cookie.getCookieId('assetName');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This is the recommended way.